# How does cocos2d use fps_images.png?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

Can someone explain to me how cocos2d uses png as a font?
I would like to do something similar as my font only contains numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you do a global search on the string **fps_images.png** , your IDE should take you real close to the following lines in cocos CCDirector class (version 2.0) :

```
FPSLabel_ = [[CCLabelAtlas alloc]  initWithString:@"00.0" charMapFile:@"fps_images.png" itemWidth:12 itemHeight:32 startCharMap:'.'];
SPFLabel_ = [[CCLabelAtlas alloc]  initWithString:@"0.000" charMapFile:@"fps_images.png" itemWidth:12 itemHeight:32 startCharMap:'.'];
drawsLabel_ = [[CCLabelAtlas alloc]  initWithString:@"000" charMapFile:@"fps_images.png" itemWidth:12 itemHeight:32 startCharMap:'.'];
```

then look up CCLabelAtlas. Your image must be for a fixed width font.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse the same image included to make something other than the FPS display the following code should work:

```
    CCLabelAtlas *scoreLabel = [[CCLabelAtlas alloc]  initWithString:@"00.0" charMapFile:@"fps_images.png" itemWidth:12 itemHeight:32 startCharMap:'.'];
```

Then to set it to the numbers you want something like this works:

```
    [scoreLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)score]];
```